# How to highlight extra paychecks in months with three paychecks?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column on my budgeting spreadsheet that shows my upcoming bi-weekly paychecks for the next 6 months, which looks like this.

[image: dates]

What I want to do is conditionally highlight the 3rd paycheck in months with 3 paychecks? So from the picture I would to highlight November 29th, 2023 and May 29th, 2024.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Use conditional formatting with a formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming payday is every two weeks, you can use this formula in Conditional Formatting applied to the relevant range:

```
=DAY(I2)>28
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it is text string and not some kind of date format, use this formula in conditional formatting:

```
=SUM(N(ISNUMBER(FIND(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(i2, " "),1,2),$i$2:i2))))=3
```

applied to range `=$I$2:$I$11`

Result:

[image]